# Made packaging design in Photoshop but now need it in Corel Draw

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-production, file-format, corel-draw

The printer we're working with says that a Photoshop file can't be printed and need a CDR file.

The resolution of my PSD file is 300dpi, but he says it's blurry.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

If the printer is asking for a CDR file, they're probably limited to printing from Corel, so.. sounds like you need to send a CDR file.

Normally when preparing files for print, you should check in advance which file format the printer works with. You either know this from previous jobs, or ask specifically *BEFORE* doing the work. Normally printers will ask for vector format files: a press ready PDF in *most* cases, or AI/CDR in *some* cases.

PSD files should be avoided for print work if possible and this is also what this printer is telling you.

Comment: But how can I export it to cdr.. ? I have improved the resolution in photoshop now it looks clear..  But how to add up in coreldraw so that he can print it..

Comment: @PriyaJain you dont. Either you designed it as vector or you did not.

Comment: So that means the designs that I had created on photoshop I won't be able to print it?

Comment: You need to somehow re-build the artwork in Corel and save as CDR. Photoshop does NOT save CDR files.

Answer (score 0):

> So that means the designs that I had created on photoshop I won't be able to print it?

When you design in Photoshop you design a bitmap-image.
When your printer demands a CDR file, it expects a vector-image.
Importing in CorelDraw is one thing, but then you will have to kind of convert it to vectors.

Select your design, then click the menu Bitmaps and (I assume, but I didn't see the image) then Outline Trace. Depending on the complexity then choose one of the options.
A pop-up menu appears with sliderbars and checkboxes.

Do experiment!
The preview will give an okay example of what you may expect.
When finished converting, don't forget to delete the original on your final version.

On the right side of the UI you will then find a lot of 'objects' and on your drawing a lot of circled spots or outlined area. 
These correspond (but they all bear the same kind of name). By selecting the ones that you want to change you now change vector-objects.

Some of your previous designs in Ps will end up great, some will turn into a mess.
But try, be critical on the result, and adjust yourself to try and design in CorelDraw.
Learn from start to give each object its own name. That will help later on by editing or converting to e.g. SVG